# Steps to configure wwan0 interface (huawei modem, movistar SIM)

Tags: networking, usb, modem

I've been struggling since yesterday trying to configure a *wwan* interface that I get when I plug in a huawei modem into my rpi. This is what I have on /etc/network/interfaces but it just doesn't work (I'm in Costa Rica and the SIM provider is Movistar):

```
allow-hotplug wwan0
iface wwan0 inet dhcp
        wwan_apn        "internet.movistar.cr"
        wwan_user "movistarcr"
        wwan_pw "movistarcr"
```

When I try to bring it up, I don't get anything from it:

```
$ sudo ifup wwan0
Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
All rights reserved.
For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/

Listening on LPF/wwan0/58:2c:80:13:92:63
Sending on   LPF/wwan0/58:2c:80:13:92:63
Sending on   Socket/fallback
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 7
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 11
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 21
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 10
DHCPDISCOVER on wwan0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 6
No DHCPOFFERS received.
No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

Also tried with qmi-network but it also fails:

```
$ sudo qmi-network /dev/cdc-wdm0 start
Loading profile at /etc/qmi-network.conf...
    APN: internet.movistar.cr
    APN user: movistarcr
    APN password: movistarcr
    qmi-proxy: no
Checking data format with 'qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wda-get-data-format '...
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
[23 May 2018, 15:47:10] -Warning ** [/dev/cdc-wdm0] QMI framing error detected
error: couldn't create client for the 'wda' service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out
Device link layer protocol not retrieved: WDA unsupported
Starting network with 'qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 --wds-start-network=apn='internet.movistar.cr',username='movistarcr',password='movistarcr'  --client-no-release-cid '...
error: couldn't create client for the 'wds' service: CID allocation failed in the CTL client: Transaction timed out
error: network start failed, client not allocated
```

Just as a test, I'm able to send SMSs by echoing into /dev/ttyUSB2 and reading from it so it's not like I don't have access to provider's network or that the device is locked down.

If I try to go down and dirty and echo a ATD or ATDT command into /dev/ttyUSB2, I get a **NO CARRIER** reply from the modem and so trying to run wvdial against /dev/ttyUSB2 fails miserably as well, just as I expected.

Modem is Huawei E303C (taken from sending ATI command to modem):

```
Manufacturer: huawei
Model: E303C
Revision: 21.157.01.01.18
IMEI: xxxxxxxxxxx
+GCAP: +CGSM,+DS,+ES
```

AT^SETPORT? output:

```
^SETPORT:A1,A2;16,3,2,1,A1,A2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok.... I was able to get the modem to connect (disregarding wwan0 interface) by using wvdial. I only had to use these init commands:

```
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","myapn"
```

Set up the correct APN in Init3 command and you should be good (plus the other usual stuff like device, phone number, etc, etc etc)

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.

Answer (score 1):

This could be a problem with the wwan0 protocol.
try to change to raw-ip as oppose to the defaulted 802.3

```
echo Y > /sys/class/net/wwan0/qmi/raw-ip
```

or

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -E raw-ip
```

to check expected data format

```
qmicli -d /dev/cdc-wdm0 -e
```

Comment: [This](http://www.embeddedpi.com/documentation/3g-4g-modems/raspberry-pi-sierra-wireless-mc7455-modem-raw-ip-qmi-interface-setup) was also helpful.